# I get only choppy audio and no video using omxplayer on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: hdmi, raspbian-jessie, omxplayer

I'm trying to play an file720.mkv file to hdmi with omxplayer but I'm getting only choppy audio with no video.

```
omxplayer -g -o hdmi file.720p.HDTV.x264.mkv

omxplayer -version

omxplayer - Commandline multimedia player for the Raspberry Pi
        Build date: Fri, 06 May 2016 14:07:54 +0000
        Version   : 6c90c75 [master]
        Repository: https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer.git
```

here is the log...

```
06:12:05 T:18446744071710231280   DEBUG: DllBcm: Using omx system library
06:12:05 T:18446744071710232274   DEBUG: DllOMX: Using omx system library
06:12:05 T:18446744071710232901   DEBUG: DllAvFormat: Using libavformat system library
06:12:05 T:18446744071710235336   DEBUG: DBus connection succeeded
06:12:05 T:18446744071710236597   DEBUG: Keyboard: DBus connection succeeded
06:12:05 T:18446744071710236767   DEBUG: OMXThread::Create - Thread with id 1901065264 started
06:12:05 T:18446744071710236848   DEBUG: DllAvUtilBase: Using libavutil system library
06:12:05 T:18446744071710236875   DEBUG: DllAvCodec: Using libavcodec system library
06:12:05 T:18446744071710236898   DEBUG: DllAvFormat: Using libavformat system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710852244   DEBUG: COMXCoreComponent::Initialize OMX.broadcom.clock input port 80 output port 81 m_handle 0x1041f00
06:12:06 T:18446744071710852598   DEBUG: OMXClock::OMXStop
06:12:06 T:18446744071710852739   DEBUG: OMXClock::OMXSetSpeed(0.00) pause_resume:1
06:12:06 T:18446744071710853044   DEBUG: OMXThread::Create - Thread with id 1888908336 started
06:12:06 T:18446744071710853170   DEBUG: DllAvUtilBase: Using libavutil system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710853227   DEBUG: DllAvCodec: Using libavcodec system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710853281   DEBUG: DllAvFormat: Using libavformat system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710853310   DEBUG: DllAvUtilBase: Using libavutil system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710853353   DEBUG: DllAvCodec: Using libavcodec system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710853402   DEBUG: DllAvFormat: Using libswresample system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854541    INFO: COMXAudioCodecOMX::GetChannelMap - FFmpeg reported 6 channels, but the layout contains 0 ignoring
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854639   DEBUG: DllAvUtilBase: Using libavutil system library
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854692   DEBUG: COMXAudio::SetCodingType OMX_AUDIO_CodingPCM
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854742    INFO: CPCMRemap: I channel map: FL,FR,CE,LFE,BL,BR
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854792    INFO: CPCMRemap: O channel map: FL,FR
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854819   DEBUG: CPCMRemap: Downmix normalization is disabled
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854890   DEBUG: CPCMRemap: FL = FL(1.000000) CE(0.707107) LFE(0.707107) BL(1.000000)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710854943   DEBUG: CPCMRemap: FR = FR(1.000000) CE(0.707107) LFE(0.707107) BR(1.000000)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710855984   DEBUG: COMXCoreComponent::Initialize OMX.broadcom.audio_decode input port 120 output port 121 m_handle 0x10adec0
06:12:06 T:18446744071710856898   DEBUG: COMXCoreComponent::AllocInputBuffers component(OMX.broadcom.audio_decode) - port(120), nBufferCountMin(4), nBufferCountActual(16), nBufferSize(49152), nBufferAlignmen(16)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873161   DEBUG: COMXAudio::Initialize Input bps 32 samplerate 48000 channels 6 buffer size 2304000 bytes per second 1152000
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873233   DEBUG: pcm->direction      : input
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873261   DEBUG: pcm->nPortIndex     : 120
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873286   DEBUG: pcm->eNumData       : 0
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873310   DEBUG: pcm->eEndian        : 1
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873335   DEBUG: pcm->bInterleaved   : 1
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873359   DEBUG: pcm->nBitPerSample  : 32
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873382   DEBUG: pcm->ePCMMode       : 0
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873406   DEBUG: pcm->nChannels      : 6
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873430   DEBUG: pcm->nSamplingRate  : 48000
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873454   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelLF
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873477   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelRF
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873500   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelCF
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873523   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelLFE
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873545   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelLR
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873567   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelRR
06:12:06 T:18446744071710873590   DEBUG: COMXAudio::Initialize device omx:hdmi passthrough 0 hwdecode 0
06:12:06 T:18446744071710874090   DEBUG: OMXThread::Create - Thread with id 1876714544 started
06:12:06 T:18446744071710874335  NOTICE: OMXClock using audio as reference
06:12:06 T:18446744071710874566   DEBUG: OMXClock::OMXReset audio / video : 1 / 0 wait mask 0->1 state : 2->1
06:12:06 T:18446744071710874858   DEBUG: Popped message member: NameAcquired interface: org.freedesktop.DBus type: 4 path: /org/freedesktop/DBus
06:12:06 T:18446744071710874900 WARNING: Unhandled dbus message, member: NameAcquired interface: org.freedesktop.DBus type: 4 path: /org/freedesktop/DBus
06:12:06 T:18446744071710875003   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:-4503599627370496 V:0) P:1 A:0.00 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,0,1) A:0% V:0% (0.00,4.02)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710876142    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:0 pts:0 size:615144
06:12:06 T:18446744071710876859    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:32000 pts:32000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710878390   DEBUG: COMXAudioCodecOMX::Decode(0x1036240,1792) format=8(8) chan=6 samples=1536 size=6144 data=0x6f4004c0,0x6f401da0,0x6f403610,0x6f40a470,0x6f40bca0,0x6f40d4d0,(nil),(nil)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710878578   DEBUG: COMXAudioCodecOMX::GetData size=36864/36864 line=6144/6144 buf=0x6f413d18, desired=49152
06:12:06 T:18446744071710878620    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:64000 pts:64000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710879703   DEBUG: COMXAudio::Decode ADec : setStartTime 0.032000
06:12:06 T:18446744071710882180   DEBUG: COMXCoreComponent::Initialize OMX.broadcom.audio_mixer input port 232 output port 231 m_handle 0x6f40a2a8
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883441   DEBUG: COMXCoreComponent::Initialize OMX.broadcom.audio_render input port 100 output port 100 m_handle 0x6f4051a0
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883580    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883813   DEBUG: COMXAudio::PortSettingsChanged - Output bps 16 samplerate 48000 channels 2 buffer size 2304000 bytes per second 768000
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883845   DEBUG: pcm->direction      : output
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883871   DEBUG: pcm->nPortIndex     : 231
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883895   DEBUG: pcm->eNumData       : 0
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883919   DEBUG: pcm->eEndian        : 1
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883944   DEBUG: pcm->bInterleaved   : 1
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883967   DEBUG: pcm->nBitPerSample  : 16
06:12:06 T:18446744071710883991   DEBUG: pcm->ePCMMode       : 0
06:12:06 T:18446744071710884014   DEBUG: pcm->nChannels      : 2
06:12:06 T:18446744071710884038   DEBUG: pcm->nSamplingRate  : 48000
06:12:06 T:18446744071710884063   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelLF
06:12:06 T:18446744071710884086   DEBUG: OMX_AUDIO_ChannelRF
06:12:06 T:18446744071710885377   DEBUG: COMXAudio::PortSettingsChanged - bits:32 mode:0 channels:6 srate:48000 nopassthrough
06:12:06 T:18446744071710899002   DEBUG: Popped message member: NameAcquired interface: org.freedesktop.DBus type: 4 path: /org/freedesktop/DBus
06:12:06 T:18446744071710899134 WARNING: Unhandled dbus message, member: NameAcquired interface: org.freedesktop.DBus type: 4 path: /org/freedesktop/DBus
06:12:06 T:18446744071710924541    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710924611    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:96000 pts:96000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710924691   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:64000 V:0) P:1 A:0.06 V:0.00/T:0.20 (1,0,0,1) A:26% V:0% (0.03,4.02)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710925005   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:96000 V:0) P:1 A:0.10 V:0.00/T:0.20 (1,0,0,1) A:26% V:0% (0.03,4.02)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710926696    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710926757    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:128000 pts:128000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710928818    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710928873    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:160000 pts:160000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710930432    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710930508    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:192000 pts:192000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710932077    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710932166    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:224000 pts:224000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710933719    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710933774    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:256000 pts:256000 size:1792
06:12:06 T:18446744071710935433    INFO: COMXAudio::ApplyVolume - Volume=1.00 (* 1.00 * 1.00)
06:12:06 T:18446744071710935529    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:288000 pts:288000 size:75017
06:12:06 T:18446744071710935629    INFO: CDVDPlayerAudio::Decode dts:320000 pts:320000 size:1792
```

I've searched and I feel I am the only person with this problem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, omxplayer does not support the `*.mkv` file I was trying to play.  I played an `*.mp4` file and it played beautifully.  Disappointing that omxplayer doesn't support more formats.  I also tried another `*.mkv` and it worked so the orginal file that was giving me problems must have been corrupted somehow.